# Do I have to declare every used component one by one in moduleMetadata.declarations in the Story (Angular Storybook)?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I am trying to write a story for a high level angular component which have many possible child components depending on the input data.

I end up having to list all the components in the story as follows:

```
export default {
    title: 'My Application/Data Explorer Component',
    component: DataExplorerComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            // here is the annoyoing bit:
            declarations: [
                MyTextComponent,
                MyTableComponent,
                MyGraphComponent,
                ...
            ],
        }),
    ],
} as Meta;
```

Since all of those child components are already declared in the `app.module.ts`, can I avoid having to list all of them again in the `my-component.stories.ts` like shown above?

The component list gets long pretty quickly as many of those components have their own sub-components, and if I forget to maintain this list, the story renders wrong but without any errors, and it can be annoying to find which components are missing in the `declarations`.